# Phase noise units: dBc/Hz --> dB(rad/√Hz)

Tags: phase-noise

Trying to better understand phase noise units and characterize a device to compare with specs.

I'm used to measuring in dBc/Hz, but the specs given are in dB(rad/√Hz)/m, which I guess is fairly obviously related to the other common phase noise units dB(rad<sup>2</sup>/Hz) <-- which I almost never see with the length unit in the divisor.

Anyways, I'm super lost. Can anyone help me convert from what I measure on the ESA (dBc/Hz) to either of the other two units, dB(rad/√Hz)/m or dB(rad<sup>2</sup>/Hz).

If it matters, it's a [fiber laser](https://www.nktphotonics.com/products/single-frequency-fiber-lasers/koheras-basik/)'s phase noise that I'm measuring.

Answer (score 1):

The power spectral density (PSD) of a random phase \$\varphi(t)\$ is denoted with \$S_{\varphi}(f)\$ in units of \$\mathrm{rad}^2/\mathrm{Hz}\$ or as \$10~\log_{10}(S_{\varphi}(f))\$ in units of \$\mathrm{dB~rad}^2/\mathrm{Hz}\$.

The quantity \$L(f)\$ is defined as $$L(f) = \frac{1}{2}~S_{\varphi}(f)$$ and is the most widely used measure for phase noise. \$L(f)\$ is generally given in units of \$\mathrm{dBc}/\mathrm{Hz}\$, i.e. the phase noise is then given as \$10~\log_{10}(L(f))\$ \$\mathrm{dBc}/\mathrm{Hz}\$.

\$S_{\varphi}(f)\$ and \$L(f)\$ are generally fully equivalent and differ only in the unit of angle.

According to the given equation above and **if both quantities are given in logarithmic form** they can be simply converted into each other by:
$$L(f) = S_{\varphi}(f) - 3~\mathrm{dB}$$
$$S_{\varphi}(f) = L(f) + 3~\mathrm{dB}$$

For further details I recommend page 22 in the book:
*E. Rubiola, Phase noise and frequency stability in oscillators, Cambridge University Press, 2009*